# Excel: Replace the value in a cell if the value in another cell is higher

Tags: worksheet-function

I have an Excel spreadsheet that calculates quasi-random attribute scores for a role-playing game using four different methods. One cell, Q20, contains the SUM of the attribute scores thereby generated. I want to have another cell, Q23, record the highest such total ever calculated.

I have tried =IF(Q20>Q23,Q20,Q23) in Q23, but Excel warns about the circular reference and the value never updates. Does anyone have a formula solution for this scenario?

Thanks,

Justin.

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass "circular reference" warnings in these cases by disabling automatic worksheet calculations, i.e. use the manual recalculation, which means every time a value changes you need to press <kbd>F9</kbd> to recalculate.

You don't mention your Excel version, but for [Excel 2016](https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-set-manual-recalculation-mode-in-excel-2016/)

> To put the workbook into manual recalculation mode, you select the Manual option on the Calculation Options’ button on the Formulas tab of the Ribbon (Alt+MXM). After switching to manual recalculation, Excel displays CALCULATE on the status bar whenever you make a change to the worksheet that somehow affects the current values of its formulas. Whenever Excel is in Calculate mode, you need to bring the formulas up-to-date in your worksheets before saving the workbook (as you would do before you print its worksheets).
>
> To recalculate the formulas in a workbook when calculation is manual, press F9 or Ctrl+= (equal sign) or select the Calculate Now button (the one with a picture of a calculator in the upper-right corner of the Calculation group) on the Formulas tab (Alt+MB).